# Multiprocessing with python objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, genetic-algorithm

I've been doing a Genetic Algorithm to solve simple 2d platformer game levels. Now I want to add multiprocessing to execute the "update" of my population in parallel, yet I haven't been able to make it work as all working examples I've found are with simple arrays, even those with shared memory, and I need to work with nested objects and shared memory.

Right now I have been trying the following code:

```
        # divide players for processes
        splits = np.array_split(groups.players_group, settings.PROCESSES)

        # create processes
        processes = []
        for i in range(settings.PROCESSES):
            p = mp.Process(target=update_players, args=(splits[i],))
            processes.append(p)
            processes[i].start()
        
        # join processes (wait for 'em to finish)
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
```

Now, errors have not been clear, as now they just seem to have issues with finding objects (logs say that there are empty objects which don't have some required property for the update process, when they in fact should have it. So I am starting to believe the issue is with shared memory, which I don't know how to apply to python objects).

**[EDIT]**

I've tried wrapping my object lists with the `multiprocessing.Array()`, yet it gives the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'type' and 'int'

Also... here is the "update players" function:

```
def update_players(players, ret_queue):
        for p in players:
            p.update()
            ret_queue.put(players)
```

and as you can see, it calls `Player.Update()`, which is insanely long but here it is in case you want to check it out:

```
def update(self):
        if not self.is_dead and not self.reached_goal and not self.finished:
            # act according to brain if necessary
            if self.is_ai:
                # reset movements
                self.releaseLeft()
                self.releaseRight()
                if self.brain_step >= len(self.brain.instructions):
                    if not self.reached_goal and not self.isMoving():
                        self.finished = True
                else:
                    self.executeNextBrainStep()

            self.rect.y += self.y_spd
            self.y_spd += self.gravity

            # check if player is colliding with floor
            for tile in groups.floor_tiles:
                if helpers.rectsColliding(self.rect, tile.rect):
                    # check vertical collision
                    if self.rect.getCenterY() < tile.rect.y:  # from top
                        self.y_spd = 0
                        self.rect.y = tile.rect.y - self.rect.height + 1
                        self.is_jumping = False
                    # from bottom
                    elif self.rect.getCenterY() > (tile.rect.y + tile.rect.height):
                        self.y_spd = 0
                        self.rect.y = tile.rect.y + tile.rect.height

                    # check horizontal collision
                    #   should be within same vertical space
                    if self.rect.getCenterY() >= (tile.rect.getCenterY() - tile.rect.height/3):
                        if self.rect.getCenterY() <= (tile.rect.getCenterY() + tile.rect.height/3):
                            # now we can check the horizontal collision
                            if self.rect.getCenterX() < tile.rect.x:  # from left
                                self.right = 0
                                self.rect.x = tile.rect.x - self.rect.width
                            # from right
                            elif self.rect.getCenterX() > (tile.rect.x + tile.rect.width):
                                self.left = 0
                                self.rect.x = tile.rect.x + tile.rect.width

            self.dir = (self.right - self.left)
            self.rect.x += self.dir * self.walk_spd

            # check if dead
            if self.rect.x > settings.SCR_W or (self.rect.x + self.rect.width) < 0:
                self.is_dead = True
                self.finished = True
            if self.rect.y > settings.SCR_H or (self.rect.y + self.rect.height) < 0:
                self.is_dead = True
                self.finished = True

            # if optimizing, check if should stop
            if settings.OPTIMIZATION_FITNESS:
                self_dist = helpers.dist_modular(self.rect.x, settings.goal.rect.x, self.rect.y, settings.goal.rect.y)
                best_dist = helpers.dist_modular(settings.BEST_X, settings.goal.rect.x, settings.BEST_Y, settings.goal.rect.y)
                if self_dist < best_dist:
                    self.finished = True
                    self.reached_goal = True

            # check if reached goal
            if helpers.objectsColliding(self, settings.goal):
                self.reached_goal = True
                self.finished = True
```

And in case any of you wants to check out the repo, here it is: https://github.com/santyarellano/GeneticLevelTester

Comment: can you share update_players function?

Comment: yeah, I'll add it in the main question

Comment: update_players has two args you are passing only one.

Comment: yeah... that was something I was trying out, but that's not it :/